# Ag-Grid Master- Details Data Update Problem

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid Master-Details Options for binding data to the grid. But in this case, I am unable to change the detail row data until I am not opening its parent/master node. For that reason, I have to open it and close it explicitly using **setExpanded()**. But using this approach, it is consuming so much CPU memory and power so it is not a good approach. I have tried many things but unable to update with optimization.I am updating with `SetValue(key, value)` method. Is anyone know any alternative approach ??

**Note:** I am using setExpanded() because i am unable to get child row node object until its parent is not expanded. Is anyone know how to get child/details row node object with using setExpand() ??